# How can I access params from my custom module in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, module, parameters

I wrote a custom module which I'm including with require "mymodule.rb" from my controller. Is there a way to access params without explicitly passing it to my module functions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer in this question, [Advice on using modules with Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932034/advice-on-using-modules-with-ruby-on-rails).  The last sentence of the accepted answer says that you're going to have to pass arguments to the module.